# Arrangements of a word

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Let's say we have a word

> MONSOON

Number of ways of arranging the alphabets of this word to achieve a distinct word is given by $7! / (2! 3!)$

How does dividing $7!$ by $(2! 3!)$ takes care of the duplicates? I know the formula, but not how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you distinguish the letters you get $MO_1N_1SO_2O_3N_2$. When you take a permutation, flipping $N_1$ and $N_2$ results in the same string if the $N$'s are the same, so you have to divide by $2=2!$ to take care of those duplicates.

Similarly, there are $3!=6$ ways of coming up with alternative arrangement of the O's, each of which yields the same end result, so you must divide by those $3!$ as well...

Comment: Thank you. That was simple. I should have tried thinking that way.